# How to filter out a row and column using str.split() in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas

How do you filter the individual column to itself?

[image]

I want to make it from

```
   0      1     2  
Action Casual Indie
Action Casual  NaN
Action   NaN  Indie
Action   NaN   NaN
```

into

```
Action Casual  Indie
 True  True    False
 True  False   True
 True  False   False
```

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "filter the individual column to itself"?

Comment: Are you perhaps after `Genre.str.get_dummies(';')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Action', 'Casual', 'NaN'], ['Action', 'NaN', 'Indie'], ['Action', 'NaN', 'NaN']], columns=['Action', 'Casual', 'Indie'])

df = df.apply(lambda x: x == x.name)
```